# How do I solve bower init EACCES error on ubuntu server?

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-12.04, bower

I've been trying to figure out this issue for some time now and I am getting extremely frustrated. I installed bower and now I am trying to do bower init. I Am able to get through the guided set up. Once I answer : Looks good? I get an `Error:EACCESS,open '/var/www/public/bower.json'` and after is console trace with standardRenderer.error being the first item. I also get an error when i just use bower install angular.

How do I resolve this issue?

thanks

Comment: From which user do you launch a node.js and what is owner and group of file?
ls -l bower.json to see

Comment: I am using the same user for both. I do understand this is a permission issue, just can't find where.

Comment: Maybe a SELinux issue? Is it on and in which mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some insane digging, I found it was a multitude of permission issues. Referencing these 2 related questions:

- [Getting "Error: EACCES, mkdir" whenever I try to install something with bower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137043/getting-error-eacces-mkdir-whenever-i-try-to-install-something-with-bower)
- [npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)

Do this order:

1. sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm ([Noah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1095114/noah))
2. sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/npm/lib/node_modules/ *to set permission on already installed modules* ([Brad Parks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26510/brad-parks))
3. sudo chown -R $(whoami) /var/www [Potecaru Tudor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2143874/potecaru-tudor)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing below steps -

```
sudo npm install -g bower

bower cache clean

sudo rm -rf ~/.bower

bower init
```

If above steps don't fix then the configstore might be removed by one of your program for some reason.

In this case you can go to open your terminal and type:

open Users/[your username]/.config

[your username] should be your username. I assume it's jason.

And then you create a folder called configstore!

Done.